# Shark for Root not working

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, wi-fi, data-monitoring

I am pretty much new to the **packet sniffing**. I found some application for the same **Shark for root**. I have rooted my phone for the application and I tried logging the packets being transferred from my mobile using the start button available in the application. But all in vain I was not able to log even a single packet, and All the time I open the .pcap file with the sharkreader It gives error as **Empty file opened**.

I am using Android Gingerbread on my mobile.

Also while stopping the logs, it gives some error executing some Shell commands like **killall**.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Ever figure this out?

Comment: Nope, I tried for sometime but never worked so stopped using this

Comment: Yea, I eventually just opened the file on my laptop with WireShark.

Answer (score 0):

See if you still have available memory in your storage. Shark for Root won't record any packets if your device has insufficient memory.

Comment: Hey john, I have 30-35MB free memory in my device while 2GB in my memory card. Can you please help me out. Thanks